# Changing style of north arrow “ESRI North 4” to “ESRI North 1” using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, north-arrow

I have a Python assignment where I have to write a script to change the style of the north arrow from “ESRI North 4” to “ESRI North 1”. I wrote the following code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"F:/Lab9/Georgia.mxd")

for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT"):

    if elm.name == "North Arrow":
        elm.style = "ESRI North 1"

mxd.save()

del mxd
```

It gave me no error, but It didn't change the existing style to the one I required.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. I'm not sure its appropriate to post purely academic material here, but perhaps we can provide some suggestions. For example, have you checked that the if elm.name test is ever true? If not, why might that be?

Answer (score 3):

I ran the test code below which is near identical to yours.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\temp\test.mxd")

for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT"):
    print elm.name
    if elm.name == "North Arrow":
        print elm.style
        elm.style = "ESRI North 1"
mxd.save()

del mxd
```

What you will notice is that the `print elm.style` reports:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/temp/test5.py", line 7,
>   in 
>       print elm.style AttributeError: 'MapSurroundElement' object has no attribute 'style'

So the reason your code achieves nothing is that it simply sets a Python variable called `elm.style` to the value "ESRI North 1" rather than setting a non-existent property called `style` of an ArcPy MapSurroundElement object.

I do not know of a way to change the style of a North Arrow using ArcPy so, if no one else does either, then I recommend that someone create an ArcGIS Idea to have ArcPy provided with a writable property on its MapSurroundElement objects.

Comment: There is no such thing as the `.style` attribute on any `arcpy.mapping` layout element object. You can't just make up an API and pretend it will work.

Answer (score 1):

From everything I have seen, or more correctly not seen, while trying to find a way to change the color of my north arrows and scale bars, it appears it is still not possible to change the type or style of north arrow using arcpy.

Also, arcpy.mapping does not allow you to add or remove graphic elements, and cloned elements can only be applied to the mxd where the original object is found.  So creating a dummy map document with every kind of north arrow you might use, and cloning the one you want will not work either.

An explanation for this is found in the discussion at http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/26979-Deleting-Layout-Elements-with-arcpy.mapping:

> Our objective with arcpy.mapping was NOT to recreate ArcObjects
>   capabilities but to simplify the scripting experience. If we gave you
>   the ability to add new objects (e.g., scale bar) we would need to
>   expose ALL of the properties associated with adding that object (aka
>   ArcObjects).
>
> **Arcpy.mapping is intended to work with already authored mxds and layer
>   files**. The idea is that we use ArcMap and all of its 100's of buttons,
>   menus, properties dialogs to author the content and we use
>   arcpy.mapping to automate it.

As [suggested by PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77163/115), this is something the community would have to request from ESRI in a future release.